# Excel VBA putting range to an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a range in an array so I can just loop them. Since there are lot of sheets that has the same range. But excel is returning an error "Object Variable or With block variable not set" on the assigning of values. The one with("**"). How can I fix the error and make it work?

```
Dim TableOldData(0 To 6) As Range

**TableOldData(0) = Range("F6:P8")**
TableOldData(1) = Range("F30:P32")
TableOldData(2) = Range("F54:P56")
TableOldData(3) = Range("F78:P80")
TableOldData(4) = Range("F102:P104")
TableOldData(5) = Range("F126:P128")
TableOldData(6) = Range("F150:P152")

Dim ColumnClear(0 To 6) As Range

ColumnClear(0) = Range("P6:P8")
ColumnClear(1) = Range("P30:P32")
ColumnClear(2) = Range("P54:P56")
ColumnClear(3) = Range("P78:P80")
ColumnClear(4) = Range("P102:P104")
ColumnClear(5) = Range("P126:P128")
ColumnClear(6) = Range("P150:P152")

Dim NewValue(0 To 6) As Range

NewValue(0) = Range("B6:B8")
NewValue(1) = Range("B30:B32")
NewValue(2) = Range("B54:B56")
NewValue(3) = Range("B78:B80")
NewValue(4) = Range("B102:B104")
NewValue(5) = Range("B126:B128")
NewValue(6) = Range("B150:B152")

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Dim RowPaste As Integer
RowPaste = 6
While i <> 6

    TableOldData(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(RowPaste, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
    IconFileName:=False
    ColumnClear(i).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    NewValue(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(RowPaste, 16).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
    IconFileName:=False

    i = i + 1
    RowPaste = RowPaste + 24


Wend
```

Comment: Don't you have to use `Set TableOldData(0) = Range("F6:P8")` for assignments of objects that are not a primitive type? Try that...

Comment: @deHaar Thank you this works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Dim Buf() As Variant   ' only Variant type is accepted
Buf = Range("F5:H10")
```

This method results in a 3x6 array. This way you put the data into an array that you can loop. 
There is another way for managing range references that is more complicated:

```
Dim rData as Range, r as Range
Set rData = Range("F5:H10")
For Each r In rData
    Debug.Print r.Value
Next r
```

Data is taken left to right then down order.